# I am having an issue in accessing dropdown list value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The problem is that I am getting the name from the dropdown list and then getting student id of that name from the table.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
        stud_name1 = ddl.SelectedValue;// sends the value
    //    Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;

        string getquery = "select studnt_id from Student where name='"+stud_name1+"'";

        getidcon.Open();
        SqlCommand getid = new SqlCommand(getquery, getidcon);
      stdid1 = ((int)getid.ExecuteScalar());// gives the id in return to selection

     //   Session [stdid1]
      //  Label1.Text = stdid1.ToString();// testing value

        // get the roll number 
    }
```

After getting the id I store it in stdid1 global variable, but I am not getting the value stored in the stdid1 variable in the button code.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = stdid1.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: why are you storing it in global variable in first place. Why can't you access it like `Label1.Text= DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()`

Comment: it is like this. i get the name from the dropdown list, then i get the id corresponding to that name form database.
when the user clicks the button to register i enter that id in the registered table as it has a foreign key relation to that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `stdid1` is a field in this class. Variables are not persisted across postbacks in ASP.NET, they are disposed as soon as the page was rendered to the client.

So you could use `ViewState` or `Session` to store it. But i don't know why you need another variable at all when you have a `DropDownList` that stores the `SelectedValue` in `ViewState` anyway.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

[**Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

**Update**

After reading your question again, i've seen that you want to store the ID in that variable but the `DropDownList` has only the name. So i assume that you've used the name for both the `DataTextField` **and** `DataValueField`. Use the name for the text and the id for the value.

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField  = "studnt_id";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
DropDownList1.DataSource = getStudents();
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i need an other variable because i am getting the "id " from the name selected in the dropdown list.
and then using that id to registed that person in the button pressed by the user.

Comment: +1 -- Definitely ViewState and Session are much better options

Comment: @MuneebHassan: After reading your question again i've seen that. But why don't you store the ID in the `DropDownList`'s `SelectedValue` property? You have used the name as `DataTextField` **and** `DataValueField`. Use the name of the text and the id for the value.

Comment: now i am doing that using the dropdown list value in the button code, than getting the id to it by executescalar query and than inserting it in the datbase.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you try moving your code into the button click event instead of the selectedindexchanged event, since it seems you don't need to make the DB call until the button is actually pressed.

Comment: but can i get the selected value of that dropdown list in the button click event?

Comment: Listen to what Tim is telling you in the other answer. I'm going to upvote his answer, and yes you should be able to access the dropdown list value there.